# Android Kotlin: Get ScrollBar reached Top

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to get the information, that the user of my app has scrolled to the top of the site. Very Information I get here or via a search engine seems to be outdated (Java or deprecated functions)

So, here it was I try until now:

```
    val layout = findViewById(R.id.layout) as LinearLayout
    layout.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
        val position = layout.scrollY
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scrolled " + position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Unfortunately, the Toast is every time "Scrolled 0". 
What can I do, to get the information, if the user has scrolled to the top of the view?

For Christilyn:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusedByDefault="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:visibility="gone"
android:elevation="4dp">
<EditText
android:id="@+id/text"
android:autofillHints="url"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:text="" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Set" />
</LinearLayout>
<WebView
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should be adding a scroll listener with a scrollable view like `NestedScrollView` or `ScrollView`. Can you post your layout xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Chrisilyn's comment, I look my XML an recognized, the scrollable View is the Webview, so I changed the code like this and was able to solve the problem:

```
val view = findViewById(R.id.view) as WebView
view.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
var position = view.scrollY
```

Thank you Christilyn!